# Display MultipleChoiceField in template of django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `CharField` with `MultipleChoiceField` formfield, and it perfectly opens a dropdown by which we go do multiple select options. The problem is that it stores the value as array like `['option1','option2']`

When I display this on template, it displays the whole array but I want to get the `option1` and `option2` and display horizontally like `option1, option2`. How to do this?

My code :

```
class Univ(models.Model):
    education_level = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

& in form:

```
 class Univform(ModelForm):
    education_level = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=EDU_LEVEL)
```

How to deal this and display?

Answer (score 0):

in models , instead of charfield use manytomany field